# Sorting Multidimensional Array using custom sort function by date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date, multidimensional-array

I am using the code below to sort a multidimentional array by date.
But as soon as the date format changes from `dd-mm-yyyy` to `mm-dd-yyyy` the sorting no longer sorts it in the correct date format.

Is it possible to adapt the function to sort it based on it's actual date?

```
function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
    return strtotime($a["date"]) - strtotime($b["date"]);
}
```

Comment: `mm-dd-yyyy` is not valid for `strtotime()` it uses `/` as `mm/dd/yyyy`.  You need a way to force some consistency.

Comment: There is not really any consistency to the order but there is to the separator... They can choose a date format order for the `dd`, `mm`, and `yyyy` but the `-` remains the same?

Comment: Then you can't do it because there is no way to know whether `01-02` is Jan 2 or Feb 1.  If any number is > 12 then it is a day not a month but that is all you can tell.